# How don't repeat the elements of a ListView on Android System

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-storage

I'm with a big problem (or not for you). The **ListView** of my mobile app is repeating elements when there are more than 15 data. I'm using the Cloud Storage for Firebase to store the data.

The code of my Adapter is:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if(view ==  null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_receitas, parent, false);

        if(receitasAdap.size() > 0){
            Receitas receita = receitasAdap.get(position);

            final ImageView imagemReceita = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemReceitaId);
            TextView tituloReceita = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tituloReceitaId);

            FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://receitas-pantaneiras.appspot.com/").child(receita.getUrl());


            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri.toString()).resize(widht, height).centerCrop().into(imagemReceita);
                }
            });
            tituloReceita.setText(receita.getNome());
            tituloReceita.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    return view;
}
```

[image: Repeating elements]

Comment: Could you clarify what _OBS_ means?

Comment: In my language it means an abbreviation for "Observation". I'm sorry for this :(

Comment: Can you solve the problem?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Because I'm a new user, I can not  attach images, but I added a link for the image

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if(view ==  null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_receitas, parent, false);
    }
    Receitas receita = receitasAdap.get(position);

    final ImageView imagemReceita = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemReceitaId);
    TextView tituloReceita = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tituloReceitaId);

    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://receitas-pantaneiras.appspot.com/").child(receita.getUrl());


    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri.toString()).resize(widht, height).centerCrop().into(imagemReceita);
        }
    });
    tituloReceita.setText(receita.getNome());
    tituloReceita.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return view;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This code is not working properly, the images are appearing one on top of the other forever, some other idea?